# « On » remplace « nous » : quel nom pour ce processus ?

Tags: pronoms, linguistique, évolution, oral

In oral and informal writing style, the indefinite third person singular (*“on”*) tends to be used instead of the first person plural *“nous”*. For example:

> Ensuite, on est allé danser

instead of

> Ensuite, nous sommes allés danser

What’s the name of this phenomenon (if it has one)? Does anyone have an example of the same phenomenon in another language?

---

Comment s'appelle le processus tendant à remplacer l'usage du *nous* par *on* (voir exemples ci-dessus) ? Avez-vous un exemple de ce processus à l'œuvre dans une autre langue ?

Comment: Je ne connais pas le nom de ce processus, mais je suppose qu'il s'apparente à ce qu'on trouve en allemand avec « Man » : « Man kann ... »

Comment: This phenomenon exists in most European languages, including German ('Man') and English ('one', which rarely replaces 'we', but can have the same generality-inducing nuance as 'on' in French). @Sylvain mentions "énallage" below, which I must admit I had never heard of, but the definition seems a bit more general that what you are describing (it means: any grammatical substitution).

Comment: Personnellement, j'appelerais ce processus "une faute".

Comment: *[Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89nallage)* complète la réponse de Sylvain Peyronnet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

En français on appelle cela "l'énallage", and in english "enallage" (that's convenient!).

In fact, the action corresponding to moving from "nous" to "on" is a particular form of enallage, which is the action of transforming a grammar form into another one.

Comment: *Énallage* semble effectivement le terme général, ce qui me convient très bien. C'est un bon point de départ pour mes recherches...

Comment: @F'x Le terme *énallage* décrit un effet de style. Est-ce que la question portait sur la variation en temps qu'effet de style ou en temps que phénomène linguistique ?

Answer (score 5):

Il faut reconnaître que cet énallage (figure de style rhétorique, donc de surface) recouvre une substitution grammaticale bien plus profonde.

En effet dans le français parlé, les terminaisons disparaissent [j'aim, tu aim, il aim, on aim, vous aimez, ilz aim]. Sauf pour la 2<sup>ème</sup> personne du pluriel, qui est associée à une forme de politesse donc incite à passer à un registre supérieur. La conjugaison devient alors purement préfixée, puisque le temps s’exprime aussi surtout par auxiliaire [on aim, on a aimé, on va aimé(-er)].

On peut donc se demander s'il ne s'agit pas plutôt d'un [adstrat](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adstrat). Celui qui serait inhérent à la [diglossie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diglossie) du français vivant (parlé) + français standard (écrit).

Comment: Sauf pour la ***2e** personne du pluriel* j'imagine ? La tendance qui pousse à unifier les terminaisons à l'oral est effectivement une raison probable.

Comment: +1, je pencherais pour la `diglossie` appliquée  à un langage selon sa forme orale/écrite, sa référence au vivant/mémoriel, ses règles d'usage/orthodoxe.

Comment: @Stéphane : la 2ème personne du pluriel m'a toujours intriguée. C'est, me semble-t-il, le seul cas où la  conjuguaison postfixée est audible. Or le *vou-z-aim* est interprété comme une élipse du sujet, jamais comme celui du suffixe de conjuguaison.

Comment: Est-ce que la question portait seulement sur le présent ? Les terminaisons ne disparaissent pas à tous les temps aux personnes 1SG ,2SG , 3SG et 3PL, et pas particulièrement avec ÊTRE.