# Pourquoi utilise-t-on « on » au lieu de « nous » ?

Tags: usage, pronoms

Pour quelle raison *on* est-il utilisé au lieu de *nous* ? Est-ce parce que c'est plus simple grammaticalement ? Y a-t-il quelque raison pour laquelle on préfère éviter *nous* ?

Comment: Avant d'entrer dans de plus amples détails : as-tu éventuellement consulté ces questions & réponses : [celle-ci](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/72/on-remplace-nous-quel-nom-pour-ce-processus), [celle-là](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/871/dois-je-utiliser-on-ou-nous) ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

D'après Grevisse, *Le bon usage*, 12<sup>e</sup> édition, l'emploi de *on* comme concurrent sans nuance particulière de *nous* dans la langue parlée familière semble s'être répandu au cours du XIX<sup>e</sup> s.

Il n'en donne pas l'origine, mais comme l'emploi au lieu de *je*, *tu*, *nous*, *vous*, *il(s)*, elle(s) avec une nuance stylistique (discrétion, modestie, ironie, mépris, etc.) est bien antérieur et présent dans la langue la plus soignée (Grevisse note que cet emploi au XVII<sup>e</sup> s. appartenait au style noble), l'hypothèse d'une perte de la nuance est vraisemblable.

(Et j'ai appris que *on* avait pour origine le latin *homo* et que l'usage de *l'on* n'est pas euphonique mais est un reste de cette origine.)

Comment: C'est intéressant ça et il me semble une explication crédible.

Comment: I'm going with this one, since the other one is too long for my taste. It carefully describes things as the are/were but doesn't take much into account semantics and usage (that are the things language is really about I think) and doesn't really talk about *why* the assimilation between "on" and "nous" happens.

Comment: "Grevisse note que cet emploi au XVIIe s. appartenait au style noble" - 
C'est intéressant, ça expliquerait pourquoi il est plus utilisé au Québec qu'en France (puisque notre français provient principalement du langage noble du XVII siècle).

Answer (score 17):

Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey), 1992, nous en apprend un peu plus :

> ON pron. pers. indéf., d'abord *om* (842) puis *hom*, *hum* (1050) et  enfin *on* (XIII<sup>e</sup> s.) est issu du nominatif latin *homo* (dont l'accusatif *hominem* a donné *homme*) en position atone. À basse  époque, *homo* est relevé dans quelques exemples comme sujet  indéterminé, emploi aboutissant à sa fonction de pronom indéfini.
>   Puisque tous les autres parlers romans, y compris l'italien et
>   l'espagnol, connaissent aussi des représentants de *homo* comme pronom indéfini, il est peu probable que ce phénomène, également observé en  allemand où *man* « on » s'est détaché de *Mann*, anciennement *man*  « homme », soit influencé par le francique. Cependant c'est peut-être  grâce aux Francs que l'usage de *on* est devenu plus général et plus  fréquent en français que celui des formes correspondantes dans les  autres langue romanes. Les parlers occitans font par exemple une  distinction inconnue du français : ils disent *on* quand la personne  qui parle est comprise dans le nombre des personnes auxquelles on  pense ; sinon, ils se servent de la troisième personne du pluriel.
>   L'usage de *on*, pronom personnel, est fixé pour l'essentiel avant le XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle.
>   [...]

Et c'est à compléter par *Le Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* (toujours sld Alain Rey), 2005,  qui dit que :

> en ancien français *on* pouvait s'employer avec l'article défini :  *l'on* désignait primitivement « l'homme en général, les hommes ». Cette forme fut courante  jusque vers la fin du XVII<sup>e</sup> s.

Et de retour au *Bon Usage* de Grevisse (10<sup>e</sup> édition, 1975)  qui note : « l'emploi de *on* pour *nous*, tout à fait courant dans la langue de la conversation, et qui s'introduit même parfois dans la langue littéraire » et il cite Marcel Cohen *Toujours des regards sur la langue française* (1970) : « il est devenu si fréquent dans le français familier que certains commencent à se demander si *on* ne doit pas remplacer *nous* dans les tableaux de conjugaison de ce registre »
Un peu plus loin Grevisse signale que dans la langue écrite, « *l'on* est un substitut « élégant de *on* ; il n'est pas d'usage dans la langue parlée, sauf parfois chez les personnes qui surveillent leur langage et parlent comme elles écrivent. »

Comment: +1 pour l’étymologie.

Answer (score 4):

"On" est beaucoup plus utilisé dans le langage parlé. Lorsqu'il est utilisé à l'écrit, c'est en tant que pronom impersonnel. C'est pour détacher le rédacteur du texte (distance). En anglais, l'équivalent serait l'usage de "one":

> One can use many different tools

Comment: On peut très bien employer *on* en tant que pronom personnel à l'écrit, pour peu qu'on ait une bonne raison. Je reprends la liste donnée par Grevisse : discrétion, modestie, ironie, mépris.

Answer (score 4):

## Nature du pronom « on »

1. LES GRAMMAIRIENS SONT LOIN DE S'ENTENDRE SUR LA DÉNOMINATION DU PRONOM « ON ».

   - **LITTRÉ**. soulignant son origine étymologique (homme) 
     1, origine encore signalée aujourd'hui par la possibilité de lui adjoindre l'article défini (l'on) 
     2, voit en lui un « substantif abstrait».
   - La **grammaire traditionnelle** y voit un « pronom indéfini». Ce terme est utilisé également par R.-L. WAGNER et J. PINCHON (Grammaire du français classique et moderne), par M. GREVISSE (Le bon usage).
   - La **Grammaire Larousse du français** contemporain le classe parmi les pronoms personnels. tout en lui réservant une place à part dans le tableau de ces pronoms.
   - Dans sa Grammaire structurale du français, J. Dunois estime que «ce pronom. rangé arbitrairement parmi les indéfinis, doit être intégré aux pronoms personnels».
   - Dans leur **Syntaxe du français moderne**, G. et R. LE BIDOIS l'appellent un « pronom personnel indéfini ». Cette dernière dénomination signale, bien plus qu'elle ne la caractérise. la nature très particulière du pronom on.
2. PAR SES EMPLOIS GRAMMATICAUX, QUI CORRESPONDENT À CEUX DU PRONOM PERSONNEL SUJET «IL», LE PRONOM «ON» s'APPARENTE AUX PRONOMS PERSONNElS.

   - Comme *il*, le pronom *on* ne peut être employé que comme sujet du verbe (alors que les pronoms indéfinis sont susceptibles d'assumer bien d'autres fonctions).
   - Comme *il*. le pronom *on* n'admet, entre lui et le verbe. que les pronoms personnels *le*, *la*, *les*. *lui*, *leur*. *me*, *te*, *se*, les adverbes pronominaux *en*, *y*, ou la négation *ne* :
     Il te cherche / On te cherche.
     Il y pense toujours / On y pense toujours.
     Il ne le voit pas / On ne le voit pas.
     Au contraire, les pronoms indéfinis peuvent être séparés du verbe par un segment de phrase quelconque :
     Chacun de vous recevra mes instructions.
     Certains, dès l'aube, avaient pris le départ.
     Chacun, selon ses moyens, a contribué au succès de l'entreprise.
     Quelqu'un, parmi vous, pourra me remplacer.
     Plusieurs, il faut bien le dire, n'ont pas répondu à notre appel.
   - Le pronom *on* se place exactement comme *il* dans une phrase interrogative :
     Viendra-t-il? 1 Viendra-t-on?
     Quand part-il? 1 Quand part-on?
     alors que les pronoms indéfinis ne se prêtent pas à l'inversion simple, mais au contraire, comme les noms, à l'inversion complexe, celle qui utilise un pronom de reprise :
     Quelqu'un n'aurait-il pas aperçu le fuyard ?
   - Comme *ils*, *nous*, *vous*, *elles*, le pronom *on* est uni par la liaison au verbe qu'il précède :
     Ils_ont entendu un appel.
     On_a entendu un appel.
     Au contraire, le pronom indéfini ne se lie pas au verbe :
     Chacun 1 aura sa part.
     Quelqu'un 1 attend votre arrivée.
   - De même que le pronom *il* et les autres pronoms personnels sujets. *on* ne peut être affecté d'un déterminant (adjectif ou groupe nominal), contrairement à ce qui se passe pour le pronom indéfini :
     Quelque chose d'inquiétant passa dans son regard.
     Plusieurs de vos amis sont venus me voir.

## Concurrence des pronoms «on» et «nous»

- D'après ce qui précède. le pronom *on* est normalement utilisé comme substitut de *il* pour tenir lieu d'un sujet indéterminé :
  | soit d'un sujet singulier. mais d'identité inconnue.
  On frappe à la porte.
  | soit d'un sujet collectif :
  « On a souvent besoin d'un plus petit que soi. »
- Il n'est pas correct de l'employer, dans une même phrase *ou* un même paragraphe. comme équivalent ou substitut de *nous* :
  « On n'était, nous, bons qu'en parlotes. »
  « Il faut prendre des mesures immédiates. - Nous, on veut bien. Mais lesquelles?»
  « Nous changeâmes de conversation. On parla du blé. de l'orge; et de ce temps humide et gris qui s'était étendu, hors de saison, sur la campagne. »
  Cette dernière construction. par laquelle on a voulu donner une couleur familière à la langue du narrateur, est à proscrire dans une prose surveillée. Quoi qu'en pensent certains grammairiens, si l'on admet l'équivalence de *nous* et de *on* dans le même paragraphe sous le prétexte que la langue parlée utilise très fréquemment ce tour, on doit exclure leur emploi dans la même phrase.
  Dans tous les cas, il faut éviter cet emploi : d'une part, l'utilisation du pronom *on* pour désigner des personnes antérieurement déterminées est incorrect; d'autre part, l'emploi simultané de *nous* et de *on* comme sujets crée une discordance pronominale comportant un risque d'obscurité, puisqu'on utilise tantôt la troisième, tantôt la première personne pour désigner les mêmes individus. La langue se corrompt quand se multiplient ainsi les cas les plus voyants de contamination, de confusion des emplois.

## Emploi des pronoms personnels compléments renvoyant au pronom « on »

- On va comprendre une des origines de l'emploi qui vient d'être signalé et critiqué. Soit la phrase :
  *Il* entre dans la cuisine, et, tout de suite, une bonne odeur de rôti *l'* enveloppe.
  Cette phrase est très correcte, car le pronom *le* est une forme complétive normale de *il*; il désigne le même individu et marque la même personne grammaticale.
  Si nous voulons donner à la phrase un sens général, nous substituons *on* à *il*. Mais alors une difficulté surgit : en effet, le pronom sujet *on* n'a pas d'autres formes complétives que les réfléchis *se* et *soi*, lesquels ne peuvent être utilisés. bien entendu, que s'ils dépendent du même verbe que celui dont le pronom *on* est le sujet; par exemple dans cette phrase :
  *On* se rend odieux quand *on* ne pense qu'à *soi*.
  Dans les autres cas, la langue utilise. pour pallier cette carence, les pronoms personnels *nous* ou *vous* :
  *On* entre dans la cuisine, et, tout de suite, une bonne odeur de rôti *nous* (= *vous*) enveloppe.
  Qu' *on* hait un ennemi quand il est près de *nous*! 
  Lorsqu' *on* a passé le pont des Dourroucats, deux montagnes s'écartent tout à coup et *vous* découvrent une chose inattendue.
- Ces tournures sont admises depuis longtemps, par la force des choses. Elles n'échappent pas, bien entendu, à un risque d'obscurité, qui vient précisément de la discordance pronominale. Ainsi, dans les phrases suivantes :
  *On* ne sait pas exactement ce qui *nous* fait plaisir.
   *On* ne sait pas exactement ce qui *vous* fait plaisir.
  rien n'indique expressément que *on* et *nous* (ou *vous*) se rapportent aux mêmes individus.
- II convient donc d'éviter autant que possible. dans la langue écrite. ce type de discordance pronominale : on emploiera des pronoms marquant avec précision la même personne grammaticale pour désigner les mêmes individus :
   *Nous* ne savons pas exactement ce qui *nous* fait plaisir.
   *Vous* ne savez pas exactement ce qui *vous* fait plaisir.
- L'emploi corrélatif du pronom *on* et de ses formes complétives *nous* et *vous* entraîne l'emploi parallèle des possessifs *notre* ou *votre* :
  L' *on* ne voit dans l'amitié que les défauts qui peuvent nuire à *nos* amis.
  Cette construction est acceptable dans les cas où elle ne nuit pas à la clarté de l'énoncé: mais, si la discordance de personnes peut impliquer que le pronom et le possessif ne se rapportent pas aux mêmes êtres, il convient de substituer *nous* à *on*.
  Voici un passage qui relève franchement de la langue parlée au niveau familier :
  « *Nous* allions travailler entre deux grains. L'herbe qu' *on* enlevait étant mouillée, *on* l'étendait avec *nos* fourches sur le grand plancher du fenil où elle fumait. »
  Certes, l'auteur utilise cette distribution de *nous*, *on*, *nos* pour donner une couleur populaire à la langue du personnage auquel il prête la parole. Le bon usage exigerait ici la substitution de *nous* à *on*.

## Emplois stylistiques particuliers du pronom *on* substitué à un pronom personnel sujet

L'usage classique connaissait déjà l'emploi du pronom *on* pour désigner des personnes parfaitement déterminées lorsqu'il s'agit de marquer une intention particulière. Aujourd'hui cette possibilité s'est maintenue. et le pronom *on* peut se substituer à un pronom personnel sujet de la première, deuxième ou troisième personne. Il apporte alors, sous la forme d'une variation stylistique. une nuance qu'il doit à sa valeur d'indéfini.
Il marque dans tous les cas l'effacement de l'individualité de l'être qu'il désigne. Mais c'est évidemment le contexte qui permet de préciser l'intention particulière au service de laquelle est utilisé ce procédé d'éffacement.

- L'indifférence : « Par la suite, j'ai souvent revu le juge d'instruction. Seulement, j'étais accompagné de mon avocat à chaque fois. *On* se bornait à me faire préciser certains points de mes déclarations précédentes. »
- Le mépris : « Qu'entends-je? Quels conseils ose-t- *on* me donner? »
- La retenue : « Allez, vous êtes fou. dans vos transports jaloux, Et ne méritez pas l'amour qu' *on* a pour vous. »
- La modestie : « *On* examinera ensuite l'état présent des problèmes de cette science du style ... »
- La familiarité affectueuse : « Eh bien, petite. est- *on* toujours fâchée?»

## Conclusion

C'est sans doute la nature complexe de ce pronom qui explique l'étonnante souplesse de ses emplois, et, partant, le degré élevé de sa fréquence dans la langue parlée, surtout familière. Cela ne signifie nullement qu'il faille accepter sans discernement ni rigueur certaines tournures où son utilisation est susceptible de nuire à la correction ou à la clarté de l'énoncé.

Comment: Voir aussi [ceci](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1708). On salue l'effort.

Answer (score 1):

En complément aux autres réponses je suggère une courte réflexion à la lecture d'un billet<sup>1</sup> de 2016 de l'*Académie française*, une institution où même là on s'éloigne assurément de l'académisme, du suranné et de la répétition d'antan. On veut mettre en valeur la richesse de la langue et bien la parler ne requiert pas de faire abstraction du savoir qui décrit ses nuances etc.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> J'en propose aussi une traduction fonctionnelle de mon cru pour rendre accessible le contenu à des contributeurs qui emploieraient l'anglais. Seul le texte original de l'*Ac*. reflète exactement ce qu'elle exprime.</sub>

---

> ## Pauvre On
>
> *Le 5 février 2016*
>
> « *On*, pronom imbécile, définit celui qui l’emploie. » « *On*, pronom
> malhonnête, qualifie celui qui l’emploie. » Longtemps les écoliers
> s’entendirent opposer l’une ou l’autre de ces phrases quand ils
> avaient employé ce malheureux pronom. Pourtant, peut-on rêver plus
> agréable et brillante compagnie que celle de ces malhonnêtes imbéciles
> puisque, entre mille autres, La Fontaine nous dit qu’« *On a souvent
> besoin d’un plus petit que soi* » et Corneille qu’« *À vaincre sans
> péril, on triomphe sans gloire* ».
>
> Si on voulait rejeter les auteurs qui ont employé ce pronom, la France
> n’aurait plus d’écrivains, l’Académie française n’aurait plus
> d’académiciens et les anthologies littéraires ne seraient que des
> coquilles vides. Ostraciser ce pronom, c’est aussi oublier son origine
> et prendre le risque d’éliminer l’humanité. *On* nous vient en effet du
> latin *homo*, qui désigne l’être humain. Quand, dans *Le Chevalier au
> lion*, pour la première fois dans notre littérature, un paysan se
> revendique comme homme, bien qu’il ait été dans son portrait comparé à
> un chat, un loup, un éléphant, un cheval, une bête, un sanglier, il le
> fait en disant qu’il est *uns hom*, une forme qui, dans les textes de
> même époque, commence aussi à signifier « on » : c’est d’ailleurs de
> ce temps où *homme* et *on* étaient interchangeables que le pronom on
> a gardé le privilège, refusé aux autres pronoms, de pouvoir être
> précédé de l’article défini pour faire *l’on*.
>
> Notons de plus que si le génie du classicisme tient, entre autres
> choses, à la concision et à l’économie de moyens, il est difficile de
> ne pas admirer ce pronom de deux lettres ne formant qu’un seul
> phonème.
>
> Certes, on le présente parfois comme une forme de corbeau, support de
> toutes les calomnies et outil des mouchards, sycophantes et autres
> délateurs souhaitant garder l’anonymat. Mais il est alors condamné
> sans appel par cette sentence qui montre que la langue populaire a le
> don de l’assonance : « *On* est un con. » À ce pauvre pronom on fait
> aussi souvent reproche de son étonnante plasticité, alors qu’il est
> comme ces grands acteurs dont on dit qu’ils peuvent tout jouer. Lui
> présente-t-on quelque autre pronom, quelle que soit sa personne, il se
> coule dans sa peau avec une facilité qui tient du génie :
>
> Une première personne du singulier ?
>
> On l’emploiera pour s’effacer modestement et ne pas employer un nous
> qui, bien qu’appelé « *nous* de modestie », pourrait être jugé par trop
> pompeux et l’on dira : *On essaiera de montrer ici l’excellence du
> pronom « on »*. On n’oubliera pas le plus populaire : *Voilà, voilà,
> on arrive*. Et, puisque le français est la langue de Molière, on
> pourra citer *Le Misanthrope* : *Vos soins ne m’en peuvent distraire*
> / *Belle Philis, on désespère* / *Alors qu’on espère toujours...* Ou
> *Tartuffe* : *Vous marchez d’un tel pas qu’on a peine à vous suivre.*
>
> Une deuxième personne du singulier ?
>
> Empruntons-la à la *Phèdre* de Racine (Phèdre s’adresse à Œnone) :
> *Quels conseils ose-t-on me donner ?*
>
> Une troisième personne du singulier ?
>
> Citons de nouveau *Tartuffe* : *Si l’on vient pour me voir, je vais
> aux prisonniers / Des aumônes que j’ai, partager les deniers.*
>
> Une première personne du pluriel ?
>
> *Tartuffe*, encore : *S’il faut écouter et croire à ses maximes, On ne peut rien faire qu’on ne fasse des crimes.* Sans oublier le plus
> populaire : *On est bien contents d’être arrivés*.
>
> Une deuxième personne du pluriel ?
>
> *Et maintenant on est attentives, on prend ses cahiers et on se met au travail.*
>
> Une troisième du pluriel ?
>
> Empruntons une tirade de Sganarelle dans *Dom Juan* : *Il y avait un
> homme qui, depuis six jours, était à l’agonie ; on ne savait plus que
> lui ordonner...*
>
> Le pronom *On*, on le voit, c’est le couteau suisse de la grammaire
> française ; serait-on perdu dans la jungle des phrases qu’il nous
> permettrait de survivre en nous fournissant tous les sujets dont on
> pourrait avoir besoin. Et puisque l’on parle de Suisse, on ne
> s’étonnera pas que l’on ait aussi en allemand, autre langue de la
> Confédération helvétique, un couple *Mann*, « homme », et *man*, « on
> », semblable au nôtre, et l’on rappellera pour conclure que certaines
> féministes allemandes avaient proposé de substituer un *frau*, qui lui
> aussi aurait signifié « on », à ce *man* qu’elles estimaient trop
> virilement marqué.
>
> [ Académie française, « [Pauvre On](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/pauvre) » ds. Bonheurs et suprises (en
> ligne). ]
>
> ---
>
> ## Pauvre On
>
> *Le 5 février 2016*
>
> "*On*, pronom imbécile, définit celui qui l’emploie." [*On*, that
> foolish pronoun, defines the one who uses it.], "*On*, pronom
> malhonnête, qualifie celui qui l’emploie." ["*On*, that dishonest
> pronoun, qualifies the one who uses it."]. For a long time,
> schoolchildren were lectured with either of these phrases when they
> used this unfortunate pronoun. However, one couldn't dream of more
> pleasant and brilliant a company than that of these dishonest fools,
> since, among a thousand others, La Fontaine tells us that "*On a
> souvent besoin d’un plus petit que soi*" [One often needs someone
> smaller than oneself] and Corneille that "*À vaincre sans péril, on
> triomphe sans gloire*" [To conquer without peril, one triumphs without
> glory].
>
> If we were to reject the authors who used this pronoun, France would
> have no more writers, the Académie française would have no more
> academicians, and literary anthologies would be nothing but empty
> shells. To ostracize this pronoun is also to forget its origin and
> take the risk of doing away with humanity. *On* comes to us indeed
> from the Latin *homo*, which designates the human being. When, in *Le
> Chevalier au lion*, for the first time in our literature, a peasant
> claims to be a man, even though he has been compared in his portrait
> to a cat, a wolf, an elephant, a horse, a beast, a boar, he does so by
> saying that he is *uns hom*, a form which, in texts of the same
> period, also begins to mean "on": it is moreover from this time when
> *homme* and *on* were interchangeable that the pronoun *on* has preserved its ability, denied to other pronouns, to be preceded by the
> definite article to make *l'on*.
>
> Let us note moreover that if the genius of classicism lies, among
> other things, in the concision and the economy of means, it is
> difficult not to admire this pronoun of two letters forming only one
> phoneme.
>
> It is true that it is sometimes presented as a crow-like construct, at
> the receiving end of all kinds of slander and a tool for snitches,
> sycophants and other informers who wish to remain anonymous. But it is
> then condemned without appeal by this sentence which shows that
> popular language is blessed with the gift of assonance: "*On est un
> con.*" This poor pronoun is also often blamed for its astonishing
> adaptability, yet it is like these great actors who are said to be
> able to play anything. When presented with any other pronoun, whatever
> its person, it slips into its skin with a genius-like ease:
>
> A first person singular?
>
> It will be used to modestly step aside and not to use a *nous* which,
> although called "*nous* de modestie", could be considered too pompous
> and one would say: *On essaiera de montrer ici l’excellence du pronom
> « on »*. Let us not forget the most popular: *Voilà, voilà, on
> arrive.* And, since French is the language of Molière, we can quote
> *Le Misanthrope*: *Vos soins ne m'en peuvent distraire* / *Belle Philis, on désespère* / *Alors qu'on espère toujours...* Or
> *Tartuffe*: *Vous marchez d'un tel pas qu'on a peine à vous suivre.*
>
> A second person singular ?
>
> Let us borrow it from Racine's *Phèdre* (Phèdre addresses Œnone) :
> *Quels conseils ose-t-on me donner ?*
>
> A third person singular?
>
> Let us quote again *Tartuffe* : *Si l’on vient pour me voir, je vais
> aux prisonniers / Des aumônes que j’ai, partager les deniers.*
>
> A first person plural ?
>
> *Tartuffe*, still : *S’il faut écouter et croire à ses maximes, On ne peut rien faire qu’on ne fasse des crimes.* Without forgetting the
> most popular: *On est bien contents d’être arrivés.*
>
> A second person plural?
>
> *Et maintenant on est attentives, on prend ses cahiers et on se met au travail.*
>
> A third person plural?
>
> Let us borrow a tirade from Sganarelle in *Dom Juan*: *Il y avait un
> homme qui, depuis six jours, était à l’agonie ; on ne savait plus que
> lui ordonner...*
>
> The pronoun *On*, as we can see, is the Swiss Army knife of French
> grammar; however far lost one would be in the jungle of sentences, it
> would allow us to survive by providing us with all the subjects one
> might need. And since we are talking about Switzerland, one will not
> be surprised that in German, another language of the Helvetic
> Confederation, one also has a couple *Mann*, "man", and *man*, "on",
> similar to ours, and we will recall to conclude that certain German
> feminists had suggested substituting a *frau*, which would also have
> meant "on", for this *man* that they considered too virile.
>
> [ Académie française, « [Pauvre On](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/pauvre) » ds. *Bonheurs et suprises* (online). ]

---

On aime sa *polyvalence*, son *sens*, son *origine*, ses *emplois* et le fait que ce soit *court*, entre autres. Son *utilité*, quoi.

Answer (score 0):

Je perçois une différence :

- *nous avons vaincu* : le **J***e* (qui parle) est une partie de *nous* : j'ai participé à cette victoire de *notre* équipe.
- *on a gagné* : le **j***e* (qui hurle avec les autres) est anonyme dans *on*, je ne suis pas responsable, mais *je fais partie* de ceux qui sont liés aux gagnants. De plus, il est plus facile de dire *on a gagné*, que *nous avons gagné*.

Dans un usage familier, *on* vient facilement dans une discussion, et peut recouvrir les deux notions.
Dans un usage professionnel, le *on* est à proscrire, surtout s'il s'agit d'évoquer les hauts faits de l'entreprise dont on fait partie : même si l'on y est anonyme, on a le devoir de dire *nous* lorsque l'on communique sur le groupe de façon officielle.

**Edit suite au commentaire**
Il est vrai que cette distinction date un peu, disons avant que Georges Marchais (tribun et dirigeant du Parti Communiste, 1920-1997) impose à la télévision le *c'est eux qui ...* dans les oreilles habituées aux *ce sont eux qui ...*
Mais j'aurais du mal à écrire *on* dans un document officiel ou publiable ; à moins que cela soit intentionnel, ou imposé par le sujet évoqué.

**Sur l'utilisation actuelle du *on***, il s'agit d'une dérive usuelle de l'oralité populaire sur l'académisme écrit qui réserve l'élégance de la formulation du *nous* aux amoureux de la langue française.
Cette évolution peut être accentuée par les nouvelles techniques d'écritures.

Comment: Cet exemple ne me convainc pas. J'utiliserais *on a gagné* dans les deux cas (sauf s'il peut y avoir une ambiguïté, et alors dans les deux cas j'utiliserais *nous*).

Comment: Ton ajout contredit Grevisse.

Comment: @Gilles j'ai une interrogation à propos de ta remarque : certes le *on* daterait du XIX° et serait plus populaire, mais la recherche antérieure d'un style parlé du *nous* semble avoir perduré. Mon énarque de chef n'oserait jamais un *on* en Assemblée Générale.

Answer (score 0):

J'utilise "on" dans les conversations informelles, mais je prefere "nous" pour les conversations formelles. Mais bien sur "on" est plus facile que "nous" en parlant.

Answer (score 0):

Je voulais poster la réponse ici : [Le pronom « on »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31357/le-pronom-on)
mais ce n'est pas plus permissible (duplicata).

---

Source [G. Mauger: Grammaire pratique du français d'aujourd'hui](https://www.amazon.fr/GRAMMAIRE-PRATIQUE-FRANCAIS-DAUJOURDHUI-Langue/dp/2010021347), Librairie Hachette (p. 152).

Ce pronom est l'équivalent, comme sujet, de quelqu'un :

> On vient.

Ou de les gens, certains :

> On dit que...

Il a pour répresentant, dans la même proposition soi, se:

> On a souvent besoin d'un plus petit que soi. On se nuit en agissant ainsi.

Dans une préposition différente, **vous** représente on :

> Si l'on lui demande cela, il vous répond que...

On, dans le F.P. fam. (français parlé familier) peut être :

- une première personne du pluriel :

> Nous, on veut bien. On n'a pas gradé les cochons ensemble ! On prend notre café tous les midis.

- une deuxième personne du singulier ou du pluriel :

> Alors, on est content(s) ?

- une troisième personne du singulier ou du pluriel :

> Voilà ce que j'ai demandé. Mais on s'est contenté de sourire (On = il, elle, ou ils, elles).

(...)

**Substituts de on** :

1. Vous (plutôt que nous) :

> Vous marchez parfois des heures dans ces pays, sans rencontrer âme qui vive (=on marche)

2. F.P. Ils (je ne sais pas si ça contredit l'écriture inclusive:-)! Le livre est vieux quand même.):

> Ils ont encore augmenté les cigarettes !

3. Les gens :

> Les gens savent bien vous remettre à votre place !

4. La forme pronominale à valeur passive :

> Il se dit bien des sottises. Il se vend bien des livres. (On dit... ; On vend...)

Comment: pour l'exemple avec "les gens", je le changerai : on ne peut pas vraiment substituer par *On* dans ton cas (je mettrai plutôt un exemple du style *Les gens savent très bien lire les panneaux (On sait)*)

Comment: @damadam Copier/coller d'après le livre:-)! Si même un Directeur honoraire de l'École internationale de l'Aliance Française ne connait pas les nuances du français je ne sais que dire !

Comment: Je voulais dire que la substitution est possible dans ton exemple, mais qu'elle semble moins native, notamment combiné avec l'usage du verbe *savoir* (je remontre mes talents en français de l'école qui ne dépassaient guère les 12/20, lol)

Comment: @damadam Enseignant dans une université française je trouve 12/20 une assez bonne note:-)!

Comment: @damadam Je voulais dire que c'est difficile d'obtenir une note supérieur à 15 sur 20 d'habitude (du moins en physique:-)!).

Comment: le 12/20, c'est un maximum, pour un profil scientifique comme le mien, c'est limite obtenir le Graal (la vraie moyenne retombe a 8/20)