# Quel est la différence d'usage entre « nous » et « on » ?

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-personnels

Il me semble qu'en général on utilise *on* là où en anglais on utiliserait *we*.

Quelle est la différence entre les deux, *on* et *nous* ? Quand doit-on utiliser *nous* en lieu de *on* ?

<sub>(Répondez en français *et* en anglais, s'il vous plaît, si vous avez du temps à y consacrer.)</sub>

Comment: En anglais, « _you_ » peut être utilisé pour « on » lorsque celui-ci est indéterminé.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

« On » a différents emplois.  Il désigne soit

- quelqu'un d'indéterminé;
- quelqu'un de déterminé avec une nuance de style (discrétion, modestie, ironie, mépris, etc.), c'est un usage ancien et des plus soigné (Grevisse signale qu'au XVII<sup>ième</sup> il appartenait au style noble); il remplace alors n'importe quel autre pronom personnel.
- sans nuance particulière, il concurrence « nous ». Usage plus récent (il se répand apparemment au XIX<sup>ième</sup>), principalement oral et familier.

Voir aussi [Pourquoi utilise-t-on « on » au lieu de « nous » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/pourquoi-utilise-t-on-on-au-lieu-de-nous/2749#2749) sur ce troisième emploi.

---

There are three uses of "on"

- one where it refers to someone indetermined ("one" in English);
- one where it refers to one or several well determined persons, but adding a nuance; that usage is old and exists even in the more formal settings;
- a more recent usage where it competes with "nous", mostly in spoken and familiar language.

Answer (score 5):

C'est purement une question de niveau de langage. Il y a certaines fonctions (par exemple comme pronom indéfini, là où l'anglais emploierait *you* ou *someone*) où seul "on" peut s'employer, mais la différence entre "on" et "nous" n'est dans le reste des cas qu'une question de familiarité.

On (tiens, justement dans ce cas-là on ne peut pas avoir *nous* ~_^) emploie "on" très communément de manière informelle ou familière (au point où personne ne songerait à qualifier cela d'erreur), mais dans les situations plus formelles, qui requièrent un langage plus élaboré, on emploiera *nous*.

Comment: Cette réponse est trompeuse car très mal formulée. Ce n'est pas purement une question de niveau de langue, puisque dans une langue soignée *nous* et *on* (en tant que pronom personnel sujet) sont tous les deux utiles.

Answer (score 1):

Dit simplement, *nous* désigne un groupe de personnes bien définies (y compris celui qui parle), contrairement à *on*, qui désigne l'humanité dans l'absolu…

Comment: Dans l'absolu puriste, on pourrait dire que c'est vrai, mais c'est à mille lieues de l'usage actuel.

Comment: @Kareen D'accord avec toi sur ce point, en témoigne le fameux *On a gagné* des supporters de tout poil, qui sont assez peu soupçonnables d'universalisme...