# Spécificités de l'utilisation de « on »

Tags: usage, régionalismes, pronoms-personnels

À l'école, j'ai toujours appris à utiliser « *nous* » pour exprimer « *we* ».

En parlant avec des locuteurs natifs, j'ai appris qu'ils utilisent souvent *on* (1ère personne du pluriel, mais conjugué comme la 3ème personne du singulier).

Ma conclusion était que *nous* est le pronom personnel officiel, qu'on utilise dans les textes formels.

Je me rappelle aussi l'usage de *on* comme pronom impersonnel (3ème personne du singulier).

Quelques petites questions:

1. Récemment quelqu'un m'a dit qu'on peut également utiliser *on* dans les textes officiels. C'est vraiment comme ça? C'est la langue qui a changé avec le temps, car tout le monde disait ça?
2. Cherchant la réponse, j'ai aussi rencontré que *on* est plutôt le « *nous* » quand la personne qui écoute (« *toi* ») est incluse dans le « *nous* ».
3. J'ai trouvé aussi qu'un canadien disait qu'au Canada ils utilisent plutôt « *nous* », alors qu'en Suisse j'ai plutôt entendu « *on* ». Y a-t-il vraiment des différences entre les pays?

Quels sont les secrets de *on*?

Comment: J'ai cliqué par erreur en demandant que la question soit "off-topic", mon intention était de la marquer comme redondante avec http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4601

Comment: @Unfrancophone: les trois sous-questions mentionnées ici n'ont pas de réponse évidente. Aucune n'est un doublon, de mon point de vue.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, on concurrence nous "sans nuance particulière et principalement oral et familier" me semble répondre aux deux premières ("sans nuance particulière" donne une réponse négative à la deuxième, "principalement oral et familier" contredit la prémisse de la première).  C'est vrai que j'ai oublié la troisième.

Comment: Pour conclure: Question 1, quand j'écris une lettre à mon chef, je n'écris pas << on >>, réponse negative. Question 2, aussi negative, ce que j'avais lu n'est pas correct, il n y a pas de difference? J'ai bien compris?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Au meilleur de ma connaissance, utiliser *on* pour *nous* dans un texte formel serait considéré comme un faux pas assez sérieux.
2. Je ne crois pas que ce genre d'usage ait court, en tout cas certainement pas au Canada. Si on veut différencier [un nous exclusif d'un nous inclusif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nous_exclusif_et_inclusif), on le dit explicitement (toi et moi vs. lui et moi, quoique *nous-autres* puisse parfois donner *l'impression* d'être exclusif...). Affirmer le contraire tient carrément, en ce qui me concerne, de l'affabulation et d'un fantasme de logique. Comme si on avait besoin de CRÉER de nouvelles distinctions du genre cuissot/cuisseau...
3. En tant que Québécois, je peux t'affirmer qu'on est parfaitement capable d'utiliser *on* à tours de bras dans le langage familier de ce côté de l'Atlantique. Ironiquement, on a tendance à penser ici que c'est exactement l'inverse qui se produit...

Comment: Pourriez-vous m'éclairer sur l'expression? « avoir court », SVP? Je la trouve dans la 1e phrase de votre 2e paragraphe.

Comment: Petite erreur de ma part: ce devrait être *avoir **cours***, et cela signifie "être en usage". C'est une expression qui s'emploie généralement pour parler de monnaie.

Answer (score 1):

> On a gagné, on a gagné ..
>    Ils ont perdu.

Les mêmes supporters, la même équipe aux résultats opposés.
Si je  dis *on* en parlant de *nous*, c'est que je m'inclus dans le groupe, il y a un effet de meute ou de rassemblement.
 
Un chef des ventes dira au bureau, "*on* a remporté (ou gagné) le marché", mais écrira "*Nous* avons obtenu de nouvelles ressources" : langue familière, contre langue (ou plutôt plume) de bois vis à vis des banquiers,
. . . mais le chef de marketing remplira l'espace publicitaire de *on*, pour faire croire qu'il est à coté de sa cible.
Le *on* parlerait donc plutôt de subjectivité, d'agglomération de sujets autour d'actions ou de faits communs, le *nous* renverrait à la pure objectivité, où même le sujet se perçois comme objet d'un ensemble plus ou moins cohérent.