# Quelle est la meilleure solution pour reprendre « on » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-personnels, pronom-de-reprise

Je fais une faute lorsque j'utilise « on » : je le reprends en utilisant « nous ». Pour prendre un exemple basé sur une de mes réponses fr.sx :

> Si l'**on** parle de laisser à un autre le soin de s'occuper de l'œuvre dont **on** est fier, l'expression qui me vient à l'esprit est « confier mon bébé » (le possessif est souvent de mise, et le verbe traduit la confiance : il **nous** est trop cher pour le laisser à n'importe qui).

Il me paraît incorrect de reprendre une troisième personne du singulier par la première du pluriel, mais je ne parviens pas à trouver une solution simple, élégante et peu verbeuse pour contourner ce problème.

Quel est l'usage dans ce genre de cas ?

---

### Edit : Pour rendre mon problème plus clair

J'utilise « on » dans un sens tout à fait impersonnel. C'est pour cela qu'utiliser « nous » en pronom de reprise me laisse perplexe.

Je sais que « se » est à utiliser pour les formes pronominales (« Quand on tombe, on se fait mal. ») mais n'est pas applicable dans le cas d'un pronom de reprise (cf. [exemple de jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14597/7224) : « Nous, on vient. », mais cas dans lequel « on » n'est pas impersonnel).

Comment: On peut aussi être remplacé par "il", cf http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/quel-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-dusage-entre-nous-et-on?rq=1

Comment: Personnellement, cela ne me choque pas d'utiliser **nous** dans ce cas. Ce n'est pas le pronom personnel, car le sujet est **ça**, donc ça me parait nécessaire d'utiliser **nous**

Comment: Ton présupposé de départ est étrange : quelle faute fais-tu quand tu utilises "on" ? Son emploi dans ton example (les deux en gras) me semble parfaitement justifié, c'est une forme impersonnelle. Non ? La preuve, tu pourrais remplacer les trois mots en gras dans ta phrase par [... **quelqu'un** ... **il** ... **lui** ...]

Comment: @RomainVALERI Le problème n'est pas « on ». Comme tu le dis, j'utilise une forme impersonnelle, mais faute de mieux, j'utilise ensuite « nous » qui lui n'est pas impersonnel, même s'il se veut collectif.

Comment: @Chop Ah pardon, je comprends alors mieux ta première phrase, la faute putative que tu décris n'est donc pas l'utilisation de "on" mais le choix du pronom de reprise.

Comment: On m'a toujours dit que **on** exclu la personne qui parle. Donc quand tu utilises nous tu est inclus.

Comment: @milk2go ON a gagné, ILS ont perdu : si ON gagne, je suis content, j'y suis inclus ! On devrait ceci ou cela, ne m'exclus pas du groupeau contraire j'y participe ; ils devrait faire ceci cela : je ne suis pas concerné, je n'ai rien à faire.

Comment: @cl-r On devrait dire : Nous avons gagné. Et ça sonne beaucoup mieux.

Comment: @milk2go C'est le français correct de la phrase, oui. Mais il est plus que courant à l'oral de remplacer « nous » par « on ». Je suis généralement plus surpris d'entendre le premier que le second.

Comment: @milk2go Quant à s'exclure en utilisant « on », oui c'est le cas dans ma phrase : il est impersonnel, donc j'inclus à la fois tout le monde et personne dedans. Je parle de n'importe qui sans donner d'autre précision. C'est pour cela qu'utiliser « nous » pour le reprendre me dérange autant.

Answer (score 3):

Le **nous** est suffisamment versatile pour servir de régime à **on** si nécessaire. Il est cependant possible d'utiliser **leur** pour cette fonction.

> Ça **leur** est trop cher pour le laisser à n'importe qui.

Le choix entre **nous** et **leur** dépend de l'inclusion ou non de **je** dans le **on**. L'usage fait que **on** est *souvent* utilisé dans le sens de **nous**, ce qui rend la reprise par **nous** plus courante.

Comment: En effet, « on » est souvent utilisé dans le sens de « nous ». C'est parce que j'essaie ici de l'employer dans un sens impersonnel que cette reprise ne me paraît pas naturelle.

Answer (score 2):

> Je fais une faute lorsque j'utilise « on » : je le reprends en utilisant « nous ».

Comme Emeric a déjà répondu, il n'y a pas de faute. « Nous » se substitue au cas manquants de « on » comme par exemple dans l'expression « Nous, on vient ».

S'il fallait améliorer quelque chose, ce serait le hiatus de « Si on » en « Si l'on », l'utilisation de « mot » là où « expression » apparaît plus appropriée et l'utilisation de « ça » pour un bébé. Il est aussi possible de remplacer « Si l'on parle » par « S'il s'agit » :

> S'il s'agit de laisser à un autre le soin de s'occuper de l'œuvre dont on est fier, l'expression qui me vient à l'esprit est « confier son bébé » (le possessif est souvent de mise et le verbe traduit la confiance : il nous est trop cher pour le laisser à n'importe qui).

Comment: Il est vrai que j'avais écrit ce morceau de réponse un peu rapidement. Je vais aller faire quelques changements. :) Le bébé ne désignant pas un être de chair, le « ça » me dérange moins, mais oui, je comprends.

Comment: Concernant l'exemple « Nous, on vient », il y a une différence peut-être ridicule mais qui me paraît fondamentale : j'utilise « on » dans un sens impersonnel. Cet exemple utilise « on » comme substitution de « nous », en quel cas la reprise par « nous » est tout à fait logique. Je crains que l'appliquer à la version impersonnelle ne soit qu'une extension malvenue due à l'habitude. C'est la raison première de cette question.

Comment: @Chop la solution de jilliagre est intéressante, car elle élimine le *on* du locuteur, qui lui n'est pas entendu impersonnel : on entend : *[moi je pense que] **si** on*,  le second, résultat d'une constatation, s'entend impersonnel, il concerne tout le monde, donc *nous*. Le premier *on* en recherche d'anonymat se heurte à ***Nous** Roi de France* c'est à dire à l'absolu personnifié. --- Le problème se déplace de la reprise de *on*, à la clarification de sa situation impersonnelle.

Comment: @cl-r Le premier « on » est-il vraiment personnel ? Oui, l'opinion exprimée est personnelle, c'est indubitable. Cependant, « on » en tant que sujet de « parler » ne désigne personne en particulier et se veut universel, tout comme dans « l'œuvre dont on est fier ». Mais effectivement, avec ces modifications, il est possible de retirer le « nous » sans que cela me paraisse choquant.