# Le pronom « on »

Tags: pronoms

N'est-il pas vrai que le pronom « on » soit très souvent utilisé à la place de « nous » dans la langue parlée?

Si oui, y aurait-il des explications à cette substitution?

Comment: Ni par moi ni par mes potes. Après... tout le monde a bien le droit de parler comme il le souhaite. Les barbares inclus.

Comment: @ aCOSwt  Alors vous ne savez pas.

Comment: Disons que je préfèrerais ne pas savoir et, qu'en aucun cas je ne saurai justifier ni expliquer des *fautes* de langage sur FSE, site sur lequel nombreux sont ceux qui viennent pour apprendre. Autant qu'ils apprennent correctement dès le début. IMHO.

Comment: Une autre très bonne raison est que cet *usage* **fautif** de *on* en tant que *nous* conduit immanquablement a des **fautes** de grammaire dans les accords de participes passés.

Comment: Je vois, je pense déceler une tendance où la notion de faute n'est qu'une notion " entre chien et loup" et vous ne partagez pas ce point de vue; pour vous il n'est question que de fautes de langage et la tendance à laquelle je réfère n'existe pas vraiment; pourquoi ne pas en venir à cela directement alors et le  formuler en tant que réponse?

Comment: @user168676 J'ai essayé de répondre ici : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/pourquoi-utilise-t-on-on-au-lieu-de-nous vue que ta question est duplicata.

Comment: @ dimitris Merci, j'aurais  dû voir cela avant; après avoir pris connaissance de la réponse (il s'agit bien d'une tendance, et avec ça ancienne) je suis pleinement satisfait; c'était une question que je me posais depuis longtemps.

Comment: @aCOSwt Je crois que la réponse donnée [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/pourquoi-utilise-t-on-on-au-lieu-de-nous/31360#31360), inspirée par un vieux livre de grammaire du français (1968) écrit et parlé, correspond à ta pensée, non ?

Comment: @user168676 Quand une question devient duplicate, on ne peut pas plus poster une réponse.

Answer (score 1):

Cela dépend de l'implication qu'une personne souhaite donnée;

- dans le cas d'une généralisation, *on* va être préféré à *nous*, avec le bien connu "On a gagné"
- Si l'on parle d'un groupe de personne spécifique, l'usage du pronom *Nous* sera préféré; par exemple "Nous avons apporté le dessert"

*On* fait également office de "charnière" entre les pronoms *je* et *nous*, ce qui peut être illustré dans l'usage d'une expression telle que "si l'**on** veut"

PS : @aCOSwt, je pense que tu utilises le pronom *On* bien plus que tu ne le penses, même si le 1er usage auquel je pense reste le *On sait que* typique des démonstrations mathématiques :P

Comment: @damadamLa question a une réponse très satisfaisant, qui a déjà été donnée et que je n'avais pas lue; la présente question sera éliminée; voir Grevisse, Le bon usage, 12ième édition, l'emploi de on comme concurrent sans nuance particulière de nous dans la langue parlée familière semble s'être répandu au cours du XIXe s.  La question à consulter: Pourquoi utilise-t-on « on » au lieu de « nous » ? 5 answers –

Comment: @damadam > Rapport à ton PS ci-contre. Oui, tu as raison MAIS je distingue **l'ensemble** de **tous ses éléments** Je distingue moi ET toi ET elle ET lui ET... (=nous) de moi OU-INCLUSIF toi OU-INCLUSIF elle OU-INCLUSIF lui OU-INCLUSIF... (=on)