# Est-il naturel/crédible qu'un narrateur utilise le mot "nous" au lieu de "on" dans un texte ?

Tags: pronoms

Considérons un journal intime fictif d'un narrateur.
Est-il naturel/crédible qu'un narrateur utilise le mot "nous" au lieu de "on" dans un texte ?

Peut-on *combiner* dans un même texte du narrateur "on" et "nous" ?

Par exemple :
"Dans notre formation nous avions des examens. On appelait cela des devoirs sur table.
...Même avec des très hauts diplômes, à cette époque, on n'était pas sûr d'obtenir un emploi."
-est-ce choquant/pédant/trop soutenu que le narrateur utilise "nous" au lieu de on.
-Dans le scénario où le nous est choisi dans la première phrase par exemple, est-il choquant d'avoir la présence de "on" dans un même texte du même narrateur ? (exemple ci-dessus)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pourquoi utilise-t-on « on » au lieu de « nous » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/pourquoi-utilise-t-on-on-au-lieu-de-nous)

Comment: @livresque : non, j'ai bien lu ce lien avant de poser ma question. J'ai donné un exemple vraiment précis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le mélange de *nous* et de *on* ne pose aucun problème dans ce texte.

Le *nous* de ***nous** avions* est d'un usage habituel à l'écrit.

Les deux *on* de ***on** appelait ça*, ***on** n'était pas sûr* peuvent être considérés non pas comme des variantes relâchées du pronom pluriel *nous* mais comme des pronoms génériques neutres, parfaitement utilisables dans un contexte littéraire (les étudiants appelaient ça[...])

C'est d'autant plus vrai dans la deuxième occurrence puisque l'auteur a écrit *on n'était pas **sûr*** et pas *on n'était pas **sûrs***.

Comment: Merci : je pensais exactement comme vous, mais je voulais en être sûr en posant la question (les phrases d'exemple sont de moi). Vous m'avez énormément fait avancé, car vous avez *formalisé* ce que j'avais compris uniquement intuitivement (donc je n'avais pas complétement compris)

Comment: Nous pouvons nous^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H... On peut se tutoyer ! :-)