# The pronoun " on"

Tags: pronoms

Does anyone have any information on why they decided to use "on" as the informal way to say " we " in French?

And why we conjugate the verb that comes after that exactly like Elle and il?

I read this while researching " Before becoming a personal pronoun, « on » was a common name. « On » was first spelled « om », then « hom » and came from the Latin « homo » same as the word  »homme » (man). Originally, then,  »on » meant « man » in general. But with time it turned into a pronoun and lost this meaning.
Still, that’s the reason why we conjugate « on » in the singular even if today the meaning is plural! "

But I don't understand how the definition (on = man ) turned to ( we or in general ) !?

Comment: Can you please expand on  what you mean by "they decided" please? Who is "they" ? Because personally I do not think anyone decided on that. *On* can indeed be an informal  way to mean "we" (but not always informal). You have to consider language history and etymology. A way to start might be to read the etymology [on the wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/on). There's are already lots of question on *on* on FL. This one might be of interest: [Pourquoi utilise-t-on « on » au lieu de « nous »?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2737/358)

Comment: You say  "we conjugate « on » in the singular even if today the meaning is plural! "" : no the meaning is not always plural. It can stand for several persons, but it can also stand for one.

Comment: Even in English, we don't change the conjugation when we start using a pronoun for something other than its original use. With the singular "they", we use "are" and not "is"; for example, we'd say "the plumber is coming at two, and they are going to fix the leak," using "is" and "are" for the same person in the same sentence.

Comment: *Man spricht Deutsch.*

Comment: I would recommend reading the TLFi entry on _on_, which seems to have everything you want to know and then some ... http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?19;s=902455710;r=1;nat=;sol=8;

Comment: @jlliagre « Man » en allemand ne correspond jamais au français « nous ». https://www.gymglish.com/fr/wunderbla/grammaire-allemande/le-pronom-man, https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-allemand/On+va+faire+en+sorte

Comment: @LPH Bien sûr. Je n'ai mis cette phrase en commentaire que pour montrer que la pronominalisation du mot homme n'était pas qu'un fait français.

Answer (score 2):

As you've gathered, the French pronoun **on** is a **pronom impersonnel** with no real equivalent in English.

It originally comes from the Latin *homo*, meaning "man". In Old French, it evolved into **on**, meaning "man, person".

Its widespread use is mainly due to the influence of the spoken word: replacing **nous** with **on** makes speech more fluid, avoiding the systematic repetition of **nous**. This has facilitated its gradual adoption. Oral usage very often influences the written word.

As for why it's used as a 3rd person singular, there's no particular reason except that it's because it's impersonal and indefinite. It allows us to speak generally, without explicit reference to a specific subject.

Comment: *One* can sometimes be an English equivalent of the impersonal *on* but English prefers the passive form: *On parle français* / *Man spricht Deutsch* / *English spoken*. There is no other choice than the third person singular when you know *on* was originally *l'homme*.

Comment: "replacing nous with on makes speech more fluid, avoiding the systematic repetition of nous": What is this would-be fluidity?There is nothing wrong then with the systematic repetition of "on"? Those assertions are mere opinion. There is no equivalent of "on" in English, where the proper pronoun is used, and no such considerations of loss of fluidity or excessive repetition. What is so special to French? Nothing, I believe.

Comment: Some phrases have become more or less impossible with _nous_. For example, _on y va?_ cannot be _nous y va?_. _Nous y allons?_ would work better, but is not as natural now as _on y va?_.

Comment: @Frank *Nous y va* would be "heretic"! :-)

Answer (score -2):

The usage for "nous" goes back at least to 1445, when the conjugation ending then used was even that of the first person plural.

> ([TLFi, étymologie](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/on)) C. *On* employé stylistiquement pour représenter une ou plusieurs personnes déterminées **1**. dans le discours direct, est substitué à un pron. pers. de la 2<sup>e</sup> ers. pour exprimer la distance entre le locuteur et autrui 1198-1202 substitué à *tu* (Jean Bodel, *St Nicolas*, éd. A. Henry, 256: Que vent **on** chaiens? [dit Auberon au tavernier]); **2**. substitué à un pron. pers. de la 3<sup>e</sup> pers. [emploi prédicatif] 1253 (*Recueil gén. des jeux-partis éd*. A. Långfors, XCIII, Sire Audefroy à J. Bretel, 1: J'aim par amours et **on** moi ensement [*on*: elle, ma dame]); 3. substitué à un pron. de la 1repers. **a)** ca 1340 représente je (Bastard de Bouillon, éd. R. Fr. Cook, 4760: ,,Biaus niés''  , dist l'amulainne, ,,oies c'on vous dira``); **b)** représente *nous*; le verbe est au plur. ca 1445 Rouen (*Farce joyeuse des galans et du monde ds Recueil gén. des sotties*, éd. E. Picot, II, 88: **On** ne debvons pas grand amende; v. ex. analogues xvi<sup>e</sup>s. Normandie au gloss., *s.v*. *on*; *cf*. Hug.).

How this came about can be seen to have the background of a period where usage was  variegated and uncertain, a period where various grammatical persons could be represented ("tu", "elle", "je"); it is only a matter for speculation as to how the use of each came into being; at the very origin there might have been an error or the will of one individual  to innovate (more likely), and finally the  locuteurs took to the practice as it appealed to them.  What is apparent from this is that at some point the third person singular was adopted, and that the switch over to a representation of a first person plural by a third person singular has been progressive (although the first phase might have been quite short), but it eclipsed all other choices.

Comment: *On* can be used and is still used today as a substitute for any person (first, second, and third) and number (singular & plural). On the other hand, the verb agreement has always been with the third person singular, The *On ne debvons* example is probably exceptional, likely regional and possibly similar to *Je mangions* that until recently could be heard in central France.

Comment: @jlliagre It seems to me that it is rarely used for other persons than the first person plural, and then there are often certain connotations attached, whereas in the case of the first person plural it is always plain "nous".

Comment: Bon, après un peu de recherche, il semble que l'exemple *on ne debvons* ne soit pas exceptionnel mais il est bien similaire à l'utilisation de la première personne du pluriel avec un pronom au singulier (je mangions, j'avions).  Les verbes n'exigeaient pas encore de sujets en moyen français, sujets dont la position était plus libre qu'aujourd'hui, dont le lien avec le verbe était plus lâche.

Comment: @jlliagre debvons? Tu veux dire que ce n'était pas exceptionnel au 15e et 16e siècles? De nos jours ...

Comment: @Frank Oui, *debvons*, du verbe *debvoir*, ce *B* étant une réminiscence du *debere* latin qui a disparu depuis. Ce qui n'était pas exceptionnel en moyen français, c'est l'utilisation de *on* avec des verbes conjugués à d'autres temps que la 3e pers. du singulier. On pouvait donc dire *on aurions tort*.

Comment: @jlliagre De nos jours, on a une nuance indéfinie, ou moins spécifique que je, tu, qui le rend peut-être plus difficile à utiliser pour une autre personne que la troisième? _On_, c'est plutôt pour un groupe plus ou bien défini, en moyenne.